# EF Core - How enable lazy loading in Entity framework core?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I've separated the Read Context from Write Now I'm going to enable LazyLoading in ReadOnlyContext by default. I also used the following method, but unfortunately it does not work.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=UniversityDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=asdasdsadasd");
}
```

my model:

```
public class Partner : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartnerUser> PartnerUsers { get; set; }
}
```

my ef version:

> EntityFramework core v 2.1.2

```
public async Task<PartnerQuery> Get(int id)
{
    var result = await _partnerDbSet.SingleAsync(c => c.Id == id);
    var list = result.PartnerUsers;
    return new PartnerQuery()
    {
        CreateDate = result.CreateDate,
        Name = result.Name,
        Id = result.Id
    };
}
```

I got this error:

> "Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'PartnerUsers' on
>   detached entity of type 'PartnerProxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported
>   for detached entities or entities that are loaded with
>   'AsNoTracking()'.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by
>   passing event ID 'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning' to the
>   'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'."

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: what is the ef core version ?

Comment: @Eldho I edited the post

Comment: your navigation is marked as virtual for lazyloading. Take a look tat his
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: @Eldho I did exactly what you said on the link you sent, but the problem did not resolve

Comment: are you getting any error. how do you evaluate this

Comment: @Eldho
'((Castle.Proxies.PartnerProxy)result).PartnerUsers' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Could you include the query and error in the post

Comment: @Eldho Ok , I edit the post

Comment: Please include your models too

Comment: @Eldho Well, if I want to use Include, then it will not be Lazy , right?

Comment: Yes if you include it will not be lazy. try this `var list = result.PartnerUsers.Take(10).ToList()`

Comment: @Eldho When parnerUsers has errors your solution not work

Answer (score 8):

You are using `AsNoTracking()` somewhere in your code, Lazy Loading won't work when using `AsNoTracking()` method.

You have two options:

1. Use the `Include()` method to load your relationships
2. Ignore the warning and simply get `null` for your relationships

You can configure EF to ignore this error:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning))
        .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=UniversityDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=asdasdsadasd");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UseLazyLoadingProxies(), you have to use CreateProxy() to enable Lazy Loading.

```
public async Task<PartnerQuery> Get(int id)
{
  var result = await _partnerDbSet.SingleAsync(c => c.Id == id);
  var list = result.PartnerUsers;
  // assuming you have access to your database context
  var model = myDatabaseContext.CreateProxy<PartnerQuery>();

  model.CreateDate = result.CreateDate;
  model.Name = result.Name;
  model.Id = result.Id;

  return model;
}
```

[ProxyExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.proxiesextensions?view=efcore-2.1)